# Data fetched from server is copying multiple times in room database

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

In my app I am using room as a database cache.I am fetching data from server using retrofit library and saving the data inside room database and showing the same data from room in recycler view.

**Problem:** Whenever activity starts it fetches data from server and saving it in room database due to which same data showing multiple times in recycler view.

**What I want:** I want to know how can I check if data already present in room should not save multiple time in room and if some new data updated on server it should fetch new data and save it to the room database.

This is what I have done so far:

**UserDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void Insert(User... users);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers();

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users")
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "age")
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;

public User(String id,String name, String age) {
    this.id = id; 
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

private Context context;
private UserDb userDb;
private LiveData<List<User>> listLiveData;

public UserRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    userDb = UserDb.getInstance(context);
    listLiveData = userDb.userDao().getRoomUsers();
}

public void getUserList(){

          Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
          ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

          Call<List<User>> userList = apiService.getUser();

          userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, final Response<List<User>> response) {

                  Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() throws Exception {

                              if(response.body() != null) {

                                  List<User> list = response.body();

                                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                                      String names = list.get(i).getName();
                                      String age = list.get(i).getAge();
                                      String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


                                      User user = new User(id,names,age);

                                      userDb.userDao().Insert(user);
                                  }

                              }

                          }
                      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                                Toast.makeText(context,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(context,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });

}

public LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers(){

    return listLiveData;
}
}
```

**UserViewModel.java**

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private UserRepository repo;
private LiveData<List<User>> listLiveData;

public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    repo = new UserRepository(application);
    listLiveData = repo.getRoomUsers();

}

public LiveData<List<User>> getListLiveData() {
    return listLiveData;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

UserRepository userRepository;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
UserViewModel userModel;
List<User> userList;
UserAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    userRepository = new UserRepository(this);
    userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    userList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new UserAdapter(userList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    userModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
            adapter.setUserList(users);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddUser.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    userRepository.getUserList();
}
```

In **MainActivity.java** `userRepository.getUserList()` fetches data from server and save it in room database.

Some one please let me know how can I get desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: your viewmodel should be requesting the data from your repository, not your activity - just in terms of architecture

Comment: please post your `userDao()`

Comment: I have added UserDao class please take a look.

Comment: check my solution, hope it helps

Comment: Please post your `User` entity

Comment: @Arka posted user entity take a look

Comment: See if my answer helps. What does `setUserList(users)` do?

Comment: @Digvijay does the data from the server contain a unique id itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_local_nobody says add this to your Dao.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

But this will not fully solve your problem. If you see SQLite [doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) it says

```
The ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, and PRIMARY KEY constraints. The ON CONFLICT algorithm does not apply to FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Your entity defines a Primary Key but it is tagged with `autoGenerate = true`. Due to this whenever you create a new `User` instance and calling `insert` on your Dao Room is generating a new primary key. This `id` does not conflict with the "duplicate" `User` in your db, and hence Room is happy to insert this one without touching the previous "duplicate" version.

The solution is to have the Primary Key from the backend or have a `UNIQUE` constraint on one field of `User` entity.

Comment: I have added uuid as a primary key and removed ``autoGenerate = true`` then too it is duplicating.

Comment: Could you update the question reflecting the modified code?

Comment: I have updated ``User.java`` and ``UserDao.java`` and ``UserRepository.java`` please take a look.

Comment: after every response for every object you are generating a random number by `String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();` There is no guarantee that for "duplicate" User ids will be the same.

Comment: ^ You can easily check this with Device File explorer in Android Studio. You will see that "duplicate" entries are in fact having different ids.

Answer (score 0):

consider looking at this annotation for room :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

with this, if you insert anything which already exists, it will simply replace it.

where you are calling :

`@Override
    public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
        adapter.setUserList(users);
    }`

try clearing the list of the adapter first

Comment: @a_local-nobody, it is still duplicating same data whenever app opens again.

Comment: @Digvijay check my update, try clearing your existing list and then adding all the items in

Comment: I have added ``userList.clear()`` in onChanged() method but when activity is opening again it is  showing data twice.I think the problem is data is duplicating in room database.

Answer (score 0):

anyone looking in the future. The best possible way to do this is to delete the table before inserting new data. e.g.

in your @Dao class define @delete query

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Users")
void deleteAllUsersData();
```

and call this query every time before inserting new data into the database. if you want the same primary key then set @Primary key autogenerate to false.